# How to convert string values (1111010101) to BitArray() in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string value that consists of 1s and 0s. 
value "1" is set if the checkbox is checked and "0" if not checked.
Example:

```
 string CheckedVal = "11100110111";
```

Now I need to convert [CheckedVal] to `BitArray()` in order send it thorugh a relay thread.

Is there a way to convert the string [CheckedVal] to `BitArray()`?

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to find this on the search results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *Linq*: we turn initial `string` into array - `bool[]` and then create `BitArray` as usual:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string CheckedVal = "11100110111";

  BitArray result = new BitArray(CheckedVal.Select(c => c == '1').ToArray());
```